# jquery deep replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a overly simplistic version of what I am trying to do.

```
var usersChoice;
var object1 = {name: 'fu',  id:'123', infoArray: [1,2,3,4,5]};
var object2 = {name: 'bar', id:'456', infoArray: [9,8]};

jQuery.extend(true, usersChoice, object1);
```

Then if I want to change my mind

```
jQuery.extend(true, usersChoice, object2);
```

The result:

```
usersChoice = {name: 'bar', id:'456', infoArray: [9,8,***3,4,5***]};
```

What I want is the old object to be totally replaced with the new.  Even just a deep erase function I could call just before extend like...

```
userChoice.nukeItFromOrbit();
```

For the record I have tried just userChoice = new object or not copying but just pointing to the original objects.  Both solutions have an annoying tendency of going out of scope at some point along the line.  (some of these objects are being passed along as a 'this' I suspect is the culprit)

So how do I do this without reinventing the deep copy wheel?  Been looking all over and all I have found is reinventing the wheel or being told their is no reason I would ever have to do what I am doing. =/

Comment: So you want it to merge everthing except arrays?  or if object2 was missing name should the end result be missing name?  (also, give me a use case for this, as I'm in the camp of never needing to do this)

Comment: the question is unclear, you want deepExtend or you don't want deep extend ?

Comment: @Abid I want to deepReplace, the old object to be nuked of all data and the new put in.

Comment: @DMoses I want to replace the old completely with the new.  If object2 lacked name then the new object would lack name now as well.

Comment: you could just keep an original copy of usersChoice (e.g usersChoiceBackup) and apply object1 or object2 onto it and assign the result to usersChoice.. `usersChoice = jQuery.extend(true, usersChoiceBackup, object1)`.. that way the original value remains unmodified and usable as a base data set

Comment: Are you perhaps useing jQuery.extend in order to copy an object?

Answer (score 1):

hmm, I hope I'm not missing something (if so leave me a comment please), but why not just extend an empty object

```
usersChoice = jQuery.extend(true, {}, object2);
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why your solution isn't working. 

'usersChoice = jQuery.extend(true, {}, object2);' 

works in scope of the sub function it's in but the change does not effect userChoice outside 

'jQuery.extend(true, usersChoice, object2);' 

does effect it outside of the scope, but with the limitations I mentioned.

Comment: Well, this requires some sample code foe the usage I guess then (to test answers against).